# I want to save user profile in local sqlite database and the user information

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

> I've done firebase authentication for login and sign up and now i want
>   to save user profile in local sqlite database. I've fetched the user
>   information from firebase and storing them in a string variable and
>   passing these variables to the Adduser function to save this data in
>   the local database.But data is not getting stored and showing "Error
>   with saving user" ,that is rowid is "-1" always. i'm new to android.
>   please help me to solve this issue. thanks in advance

---

### java file

```
 package com.example.mansi.busezon;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ContentValues;
mport android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mansi.busezon.data.dbContract;
import com.example.mansi.busezon.data.dbHelper;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
i
public class SELL_BUY extends AppCompatActivity {
   // private  dbHelper mDbHelper;
    String name;
    String email ;
    String address ;
    String phoneno ;
    String password ;
    //String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell__buy);

            check();


        TextView BUY= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buy);
                BUY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //create intent to open the activity
                       Intent BUYintent= new Intent(SELL_BUY.this,HomeActivity.class);
                        //start the new activity
                        startActivity(BUYintent);
                    }
                });

                TextView SELL= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sell);
                SELL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //create intent to open the activity
                        Intent SELLintent= new Intent(SELL_BUY.this,SellHomepage.class);
                        //start the new activity
                        startActivity(SELLintent);
                    }
                });
            }
    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SELL_BUY.this, profile_page.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    private void check()
    {
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        //database reference pointing to demo node
//        DatabaseReference demoRef = rootRef.child("CI8hvEW0sfZ0oU1GziTpGYPJv2z2");
//        String value = "User22";
//        //push creates a unique id in database
//        demoRef.push().setValue(value);
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            String userId=getIntent().getStringExtra("Id");
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        if(ds.getKey().equals(userId))
                        {
                            //name1="aakritijohar";

                            name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                            email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                            address = ds.child("addres").getValue(String.class);
                            phoneno = ds.child("phoneno").getValue(String.class);
                            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
                            textView.setText(phoneno);
                            password = ds.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                            Toast.makeText(SELL_BUY.this, email + " " + ds.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            insertUser(name,email,address,phoneno,password);
                        }
                    }
                Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
                if(extras!=null) {
                    String name = extras.getString("name");
                }

                }

            @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

        });
    }

    private void insertUser(String nameString,String EMAILString,String addressString,String numbertString,String pass) {
        // Create database helper
        dbHelper mDbHelper = new dbHelper(this);

        // Gets the database in write mode
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();




        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_USER_NAME, nameString);
        values.put(dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL, EMAILString);
        values.put(dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_number, numbertString);
        values.put(dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_address, addressString);
        values.put(dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_password, pass);

        // Insert a new row for user in the database, returning the ID of that new row.
        long newRowId = db.insert(dbContract.userEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the insertion was successful
        if (newRowId == -1) {
            // If the row ID is -1, then there was an error with insertion.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error with saving user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast with the row ID.
            Toast.makeText(this, "user saved " + newRowId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

        }
```

---

### database helper class

```
   package com.example.mansi.busezon.data;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;




/**
 * Database helper for Pets app. Manages database creation and version management.
 */
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = dbHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    /** Name of the database file */
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user.db";

    /**
     * Database version. If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
     */
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of {@link dbHelper}.
     *
     * @param context of the app
     */
    public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the database is created for the first time.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the pets table
        String SQL_CREATE_USER_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE " + dbContract.userEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + dbContract.userEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_address + " VARCHAR, "
                + dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_number + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, "
                + dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, "
                + dbContract.userEntry.COLUMN_password + " VARCHAR NOT NULL );";

        // Execute the SQL statement
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the database needs to be upgraded.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // The database is still at version 1, so there's nothing to do be done here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest Android's Room database for a local database. It's very simple for beginners https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code as it is.

As such I suspect that your issue may be that you have changed the table structure since running the App.

- e.g. by adding a new column and then changing the code accordingly

However, that you have then not taken into consideration that the `onCreate` method only gets automatically invoked when the database is created.

That is the 'onCreate' method does not run every time the App is started.

I'd suggest that deleting the App's data or uninstalling the App and then rerunning the App will resolve the issue.

If that doesn't resolve the issue then please check the log as that should contain a stack-trace for when the `insert` comes across the issue even though the App doesn't itself crash (you could use the `insertOrThrow` method instead of `insert` which would then result in an exception/crash).

If you then still have issues, please update the question to include the stack-trace.